# Run stored procedures in parallel in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

I have a master table with country codes. I have a single stored procedure to generate invoices for all countries.

I need to run the stored procedure in parallel, to generate the invoices.

How do I run a stored procedure in parallel?

Ex:

```
EXEC usp_GenerateInvoice <Country Code>
```

No of countries will be differing for each day based `<Flag>` in `Master` table. So I need to call the stored procedure dynamically

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately as posted your question is extremely vague. Are you trying to call the same procedure multiple times? I just can't for the life of me figure out what you are asking here.

Comment: Seems quite relevant. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34947/can-i-launch-a-stored-procedure-and-immediately-return-without-waiting-for-it-to

Comment: Yes I am trying to call the same procedure multiple times simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

Write a client application that can run asynchronously or multi-threaded, and call the stored procedure in parallel threads from that application.

You can do it from SSIS by creating Execute SQL tasks that will run in parallel.

You can NOT do this from another stored procedure.

Comment: I want to call through a stored procedure or SSIS